# 401 during access token setup

Tags: php, oauth, soundcloud

I've been attempting to get this working for the past day or so without any luck. I've finally simplified the code down to it's bare minimum and can't seem to find a solution.

The $callbackURL is set to the same page so it calls this page back and returns successfully after the Soundcloud confirmation step.

```
<?php
require_once ("inc/Soundcloud.php");

$client_id = 'CLIENT_ID';
$secret = 'SECRET_KEY';
$callbackURL = "CALL_BACK_URL";

if (!isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $client = new Services_Soundcloud($client_id, $secret, $callbackURL );
    $client -> setCurlOptions(array(CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1, CURLOPT_CAINFO => $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '\\audio\\lib\\inc\\cacert.pem'));

    if (!isset($accessToken)) {
        $authorizeUrl = $client -> getAuthorizeUrl(array('scope' => 'non-expiring'));
        echo "<a href='$authorizeUrl'>Connect</a>";
    }

} else {

    $client = new Services_Soundcloud($client_id, $secret, $callbackURL );
    $client -> setCurlOptions(array(CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1, CURLOPT_CAINFO => $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '\\audio\\lib\\inc\\cacert.pem'));
    $accessToken = $client -> accessToken($_GET['code']);
    echo "Token: $accessToken";
    $client -> setAccessToken($accessToken["access_token"]);
}
?>
```

The error:

```
[27-Mar-2013 16:02:59 America/New_York] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Services_Soundcloud_Invalid_Http_Response_Code_Exception' with message 'The requested URL responded with HTTP code 401.' in D:\web\audio\lib\inc\Soundcloud.php:941
Stack trace:
#0 D:\web\audio\lib\inc\Soundcloud.php(817): Services_Soundcloud->_request('https://api.sou...', Array)
#1 D:\web\audio\lib\inc\Soundcloud.php(332): Services_Soundcloud->_getAccessToken(Array, Array)
#2 D:\web\audio\lib\auth.php(20): Services_Soundcloud->accessToken('...')
#3 {main}
  thrown in D:\web\audio\lib\inc\Soundcloud.php on line 941
```

The issue is I continually get a 401 error on the $client->accessToken($_GET['code']) step despite $_GET['code'] being set properly. If I remove the CURLOPT_CAINFO I get the "Response Code 0" issue but I've worked past that.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

IIS with PHP 5.4

EDIT: The issue was resolved with an absolute path to the PEM file for CURL. It was inconsistent in our test setup as we tried to use a relative path rather than absolute. I came to the conclusion after running CURL in verbose. Additionally, Soundcloud was suffering problems which made debugging this issue difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code started working intermittently after posting this question, the issue appears to be with Soundcloud's servers or something odd going on. Not sure how it fixed but with 0 code changes a refresh returned a token. Attempting it again gave me a 401. Not sure the cause but the above code should give you your token (eventually).

Answer (score 0):

The set curl options you shouldn't need when using the SDK.

There is some more documentation here as well.

https://github.com/mptre/php-soundcloud

Comment: On Windows it unfortunately is required to sometimes supply a .pem file for CURL.